# R read data from a text file

Tags: r, read.table

I have a challenging file-reading task.
I have a `.txt` file from a typical old accounting department (with headers, titles, pages and the useful tabulated quantitative and qualitative information). It looks like this:
[image: How the data looks]

From this file I am trying to do two tasks (with `read.table` and scan):

1) extract the information which is tabulated between `|` which is the accounting information (any trial ended in a not easy data frames or character vectors)

[image: tabulated info to be extracted]

2) include as a variable each subtitle which begins with "Customers" in the text file: as you can see the Customer info is a title, then comes the accounting info (payables), then again another customer and the accounting info and so on. So is not a column, but a row (?)

I´ve been trying with `read.table` (several `sep` and `quote` parameters) and with scan and then having tried to work with the character vectors.

Thanks!!

Comment: You will have better luck using `read.fwf()` since this is a fixed width file.

Comment: I don't think `read.fwf ` will help at all or for that matter any of the standard methods.

Answer (score 1):

I've been there before so I kind of know what you're going through.

I've got 2 news for you, one bad, one good. The bad one is I have read-in these types of files in SAS tons of times but never in R - however 
the good news is I can give you some tips so you can work it out in R.

So the strategy is as follow:

1) You're going to read the file into a dataframe that contains **only** a single column. This column is character and will hold
a whole line of your input file. i.e. length is 80 if the largest line in your file is 80 long.

2) Now you have a data frame where every record equals a line in your input file. At this point you may want to check your 
dataframe has the same number or records as per lines in your file.

3) Now you can use `grep` to get rid-off or keep only those lines that meet your criteria (ie subtitle which begins with "Customers").
You may find regular expressions really useful here.

4) Your dataframe now only have records that matches 'Customer' patterns and table patterns 
(i.e line begin with `'Country'` or `/\d{3} \d{8}/` or `'   Total'`).

5) What you need now is to create a group variable that increment +1 every time it finds 'Customer'. So group=1 will repeat the same value until it finds 'Customer 010343' where group is now group=2. Or even better your group can be customer id until a new id is found. You need to somehow retain the id until a new id is found.

From the last step you're pretty much done as you will be able to identify customers and tables pretty easy. You may want to create a function that output your table strings in a tabular format.

Whether you process them in a single table or split the data frame in n data frame to process them individually is up to you.

In SAS there is this concept of pointer (@) and retention (retain statement) where each line matching a criteria can be process differently from other criterias so you output data set already contains columns and customer info in a tabular format.

Well hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks Altons! I will have this strategy in mind but with R eyes....let´s see what happens!